# Compare the rows of two columns in one dataframe if they exist another dataframe | python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `combined` which is have two columns `c1,c2`

combine:

```
 c1    c2
dr123 di878
dr987 di082
dr751 di715
dr156 di083
```

Another dataframe called `specific` have `c1,c2,c3`

specific:

```
 c1     c2    c3
dr987 di082 ekeodk
dr805 di827 sbdxdp
dr852 di737 pmzqde
dr751 di715 nedoas
```

I want to compare the values of `c1,c2` **come together** in `combined` if they exist in `specific`, add a column in `combined` called `label` and put 1, if not put 0

So, the output dataframe will be this:

```
     c1    c2    label
    dr123 di878    0
    dr987 di082    1
    dr751 di715    1
    dr156 di083    0
```

I need an efficient way to do that because my combined dataframe have ~ 8 million rows, Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
In [312]: df1['label'] = df1.merge(df2[['c1', 'c2']], how='left', indicator=True
                                   )['_merge'].eq('both').astype(int)

In [313]: df1
Out[313]:
      c1     c2  label
0  dr123  di878      0
1  dr987  di082      1
2  dr751  di715      1
3  dr156  di083      0
```

Alternatively, see if set hashing helps

```
In [88]: cols = ['c1', 'c2']

In [89]: mapper = {tuple(x[cols]) for _, x in df2.iterrows()}

In [90]: df1.apply(lambda x: tuple(x[['c1', 'c2']]) in mapper, axis=1).astype(int)
Out[90]:
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: So, my combined dataframe is ~ 8 millions, so this merge step took long time and then crash

Comment: I try it, it's very sloooow (take an hour till finish)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
x = pd.merge(combine, specific, how = 'left', on = ['c1', 'c2'], indicator = 'Exist')
x['Exist'] = x['Exist'].map({'left_only': 0, 'both': 1})
combine['label'] = x['Exist']
```

Out:

```
      c1     c2  label
0  dr123  di878      0
1  dr987  di082      1
2  dr751  di715      1
3  dr156  dr083      0
```

Comment: Same as above, my combined ~ 8 million, so it crash

Comment: Have you considered slicing your dataframe and doing it?